# Remove duplicates from cells with case-insensitive in excel using macro

Tags: excel, vba

I need to write a macro, which needs to remove all the duplicate values from the cell with case-insensitive.

For an instance, consider 'Account name' and Account Name are the two data cells present in an A column of an excel sheet, the output should display only one Row with either of the data.

Please let me if I'm missing any information here.

Comment: Please edit your post  to provide code you already tried or errors that you  received.

Comment: ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lRow, 1)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes, this is the code which I'm using to just remove all the duplicates. But I need more knowledge to do it so.

Answer (score 0):

There is no much more to it. I do not really understand what else you want.

Comment: Account Name,
'Account Name',
Account name,

The mentioned is the data which I got after executing the code with remove duplicate function.

ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lRow, 1)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes,

My expectation is,I need to get only one value irrespective of caps or small letters.

Comment: ok, sorry did not get it in the first place. You would probaly have to add a couple of columns. With this :  =UPPER(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"'","")) , careful, there is a ' between the first ", you could remove the special character and set everything to uppercase. You could then remove duplicates on that column. If you have more special chars, you might want to repeat that step.